# Can't send a file with byte array to rest API more than 2kb packet at a time with stream-octet in dotnet 6 winform

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tcp

I am trying to send a firmware file in a byte array format to a API, I'm breaking down the file and sending it, but can send only 2kb packets at at time in dotnet 6. mean while in JavaScript I can easily send 32kb packets. I even checked the Wireshark log but nothing can be seen not sure where the packet is going; anything more than 2kb fails. Here is my code for reference. Here you can see in `int var` I'm specifying the size. How can I step it up to 32kb in dotnet?

I tried different ways to chunk data and send but no luck so far.

the exception I am getting

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Requests

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

```
 public void fnUpdateFirmware()
        {
            bool blnUpdateDone = false;
            #region Initialize FW Update Call

            // filePath = "D:\\Work\\BitBucket_Projects\\LMS_2.1.0\\Working\\lion-management-suite\\solutions\\LioN Management Suite V2\\src\\bin\\Debug\\firmwares\\935708001\\V11.1.4.16\\dig_light_8dido_mp.fwu";
            Data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            data = "size=" + Data.Length;
            array1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            uri = new Uri(http + DeviceIp + fwupdate);//"http://192.168.1.10/fwup_install"
            httpSend.uri = uri;
            httpSend.DigestAuth = true;
            httpSend.method = "POST";
            httpSend.username = UName;// "admin";
            httpSend.password = Pwd;// "private";
            httpSend.senddata = array1;
            httpSend.contentType = "text/plain";

            //Start = false;
            fnUpdateCallAuthentication(ref httpSend);
            // textBox1.Text = "Device Initialize Successfully !";

            #endregion

            #region Firmware Update 

            //filePath = "D:\\Work\\BitBucket_Projects\\LMS_2.1.0\\Working\\lion-management-suite\\solutions\\LioN Management Suite V2\\src\\bin\\Debug\\firmwares\\935708001\\V11.1.4.16\\dig_light_8dido_mp.fwu";
            Data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            int sendbytes = 0;
            int Var = 1024*2;
            int Len = Convert.ToInt32(Data.Length / Var);
            int Counter = 0;
            //HttpSendDataReq httpSend = new HttpSendDataReq();

            while (Data.Length > sendbytes)
            {
                if (Counter < Len)
                {
                    array1 = new byte[Var];

                    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (sendbytes < Data.Length)
                        {
                            array1[i] = Data[sendbytes];
                            sendbytes++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Counter++;
                    // textBox1.Text = Counter.ToString();
                }
                else
                {

                    array1 = new byte[Data.Length - (Var * Len)];
                    //textBox1.Text += "Remaining Array Length = " + array1.Length.ToString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        array1[i] = Data[sendbytes];
                        sendbytes++;
                    }
                }


                uri = new Uri(http + DeviceIp + fwupdate);
                httpSend.uri = uri;
                httpSend.DigestAuth = true;
                httpSend.method = "POST";
                httpSend.username = UName;// "admin";
                httpSend.password = Pwd;// "private";
                httpSend.senddata = array1;
                httpSend.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                // Start = false;
                fnUpdateCallAuthentication(ref httpSend);
            }
            //textBox1.Text += "\n Firmware file sent successfully !";
            #endregion


            //return blnUpdateDone;
        }


 private string fnUpdateCallAuthentication(ref HttpSendDataReq sendData)
        {
            try
            {
                // AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
                // HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
                // HttpClient httpClient = Htt
                WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(sendData.uri);

                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;

                NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(sendData.username, sendData.password);

                CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
                myCredentialCache.Add(sendData.uri, "Digest", myNetworkCredential);

                myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
                myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

                if (sendData.method.ToLower() == "post")
                {
                    myHttpWebRequest.Method = sendData.method;
                    myHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
                    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = sendData.contentType;
                    if (null == sendData.senddata)
                    {
                        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = sendData.senddata.Length;


                        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                        requestWriter.Write(sendData.sendraw);
                        requestWriter.Close();
                        requestWriter = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
                        requestStream.Write(sendData.senddata, 0, sendData.senddata.Length);
                        requestStream.Close();
                    }
                }

                using (WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {

                    Stream responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    sendData.response = responseStream;

                    StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

                    string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    sendData.resstring = pageContent;

                    responseStream.Close();

                    myWebResponse.Close();
                    // Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
                    if (pageContent.Contains("FWUP_STATE_RDY4RST"))
                    {
                        // textBox1.Text += pageContent;
                        start = true;
                    }
                    return pageContent;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // textBox2.Text += e.Message;
                return null;
            }


        }
```

Comment: I would really recommend creating a *minimal* reproducible example. The core part, i.e. creating and using the webrequest, is buried in so much irrelevant code. If there is any limit it should be due to timeouts or some max object size. And it will be far larger than 32kb. Also note that "packet" usually refer to tcp/ip packets. If you are using http you are sending *messages*, or *requests*, and many packets will be used to send a single message.

Comment: Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.